# How to convert JSON object to Objective-C Cocoa object?

Tags: objective-c, json

Am developing a cocoa application, where I have to invoke java web scripts and fetch the response of the web script object and convert it into Objective C readable objects. I would then need to manipulate the fetched data for import, print, etc.

How to I interact with the web script and convert into cocoa readable objects?

Any pointers on the same, will be appreciated.

Thanks,
Nana

Comment: It is JavaScript Object Notation.. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON

Answer (score 3):

1. Convert the JSON string into an `NSDictionary` using tools like yajl, JSONKit or iOS5 JSON
2. Use https://github.com/elado/jastor to convert this NSDictionary to a real Objective-C class with typed properties, nested properties, arrays etc.

Answer (score 1):

In iOS 5 native JSON parsing is supported ([documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html)). In addition you can use a number of third party libraries to download and parse JSON (see [JSONKit](https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit) and [HTTPRiot](https://github.com/ognen/httpriot/) or [RestKit](http://restkit.org/))

A full reference of awesome libraries can be found [here](http://iosframeworks.com/frameworks).